# Возможно ли при создании пароля в кошелька bitcoin qt задать собственную соль?

Tags: bitcoin

В bitcoin qt когда задаешь пароль кошельку, в wallet dat создаются шифрованные и хешированные значения пароля, соли и числа итераций(6ce38....3c582d724214,a08e54c3106fe5fd,120074).Мне хотелось узнать возможно ли изменить криптографию задающую соль, чтобы самому задать значение соли(a08e54c3106fe5fd).В bitcoin qt по моему для шифрования и хеширования используется криптография openssl с aes256cbc шифрованием.Еще хотел бы узнать у программистов можно ли создать программу которая шифровала и хешировала  также как в bitcoin qt но только чтоб  соль задавал я сам,я имею в виду значение соли(a08e54c3106fe5fd) в wallet dat.Я не знаток в криптографии и может не правильно понимаю как  шифруются данные.

Answer (score 0):

Вариант 1. Скомпилировать свой bitcoin-qt, и поменять код, где соль составляется случайным образом.

Вариант 2. При помощи сторонних утилит вы можете редактировать уже готовый `wallet.dat`. Как пример, можете посмотреть широко известный [pywallet](https://github.com/joric/pywallet). Делать то, что вам нужно, он не умеет, но он умеет читать, расшифровывать, и сохранять обновленный `wallet.dat`. Если вы разберетесь в нем (а это не так сложно, кода немного), то сможете заменить соль на какую-угодно.

Comment: @AzarSafarov Вы смотрите в метод, который принимает на вход соль. Эта соль генерируется в `wallet.cpp`, `CWallet::EncryptWallet` при помощи `GetStrongRandBytes`.

Comment: 2 вариант сработает, если у вас есть пароль, вы расшифруете приватные ключи, дальше создадите новую соль, с ее помощь создадите новые ключи для AES, а дальше снова шифруете приватные ключи.

Comment: @AzarSafarov я написал, что pywallet не умеет этого делать, вам нужно доработать его

Comment: @AzarSafarov стековерфлов это не место где люди ищут фриланс. Здесь просто отвечают на интересные вопросы.